# How to deposit a cheque issued to an associate in my business into my business account?

Tags: canada, banking, check

A customer paid with a cheque made out to an associate in my business instead of the business name. How can I deposit this cheque into my business account ?

Comment: It's best to avoid doing business with either customers like that, or associates like that!

Answer (score 6):

Have the check reissued to the proper payee.

Answer (score 2):

Just have the associate sign the back and then deposit it.  It's called a third party cheque and is perfectly legal.  I wouldn't be surprised if it has a longer hold period and, as always, you don't get the money if the cheque doesn't clear.

Now, you may have problems if it's a large amount or you're not very well known at the bank.  In that case you can have the associate go to the bank and endorse it in front of the teller with some ID.  You don't even technically have to be there.  Anybody can *deposit* money to your account if they have the account number.

He could also just deposit it in his account and write a cheque to the business.

Comment: Depositing the money into the associate's accounting and then writing a subsequent cheque to the business is asking for trouble. This is creating an unnecessarily complex paper trail.